# nextjs - how to access cookie in axios interceptors

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, cookies, axios

I am trying to get the `accessToken` from my browser cookies, and attach it in my request's `header.Authorization`

I tried to use `cookies-next` and `const accessToken = getCookie("accessToken");`,
but it returns `undefined`.

I also checked the browser and confirm that `accessToken` exists in my cookies
[image]

api/axios.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

const defaultOptions = {
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  withCredentials: true,
};

// Create instance
let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

// Set the AUTH token for any request
instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const accessToken = getCookie("accessToken");
  console.log({ accessToken });
  config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  return config;
});

export default instance;
```

page.tsx

```
"use client";

import axios from '../api/axios';

export default function Home() {
  const getUser = async () => {
    const getUserRes = await axios.get('/users');
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getUser}>Get user</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Why the `accessToken` is `undefined`?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution other than adding the token to every request?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the fact that the `getCookes` function from `cookies-next` is not able to access the cookies because it's being called outside of a browser enviorenment.

In you case, the `getCookies` function is being called in the `axios.interceptors.request.use` function, which is executed in the server-side during the build process. At this time, there is no browser environment variable, hence the cookie cannot be accessed.

To solve this issue, you could move the logic of setting the `Authorization` header inside the `getUser` in your `page.tsx`. This way, the `getCookie` function will be called in the browser environment.

page.tsx:

```
import axios from '../api/axios';
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";

export default function Home() {
 const getUser = async () => {
    const accessToken = getCookie("accessToken");
    console.log({ accessToken });
    const getUserRes = await axios.get('/users', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    });
 };
 return (
    <>
      <button onClick={getUser}>Get user</button>
    </>
 );
}
```

And remove the interceptor from your axios.ts file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const defaultOptions = {
 baseURL: "http://localhost:3001",
 headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
 },
 withCredentials: true,
};

// Create instance
let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

export default instance;
```

Comment: Hi, but in this case i will need to attach the token to all my requests